# How limit OData results in a WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently developing an application which uses a Web API to return data which is stored in a database.

Now, I need to be able to filter the results, so OData to the request, that way I can built an entire filter in a query string.

Here's the configuration of the OData:

```
private static void ConfigureOData(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<GenericArticle>("GenericArticle");
    config.MapODataServiceRoute(routeName: "ODataRoute", routePrefix: "OData", model: builder.GetEdmModel());

    // Defines the configuration for OData.
    var queryAttribute = new QueryableAttribute
    {
        MaxTop = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OData:MaxTop"]),
        PageSize = 2
    };

    config.EnableQuerySupport(queryAttribute);
}
```

This method is being called from within the `WebApiConfig.cs` file.

The `Global.asax` file does contain the following code:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();

    UpdateDatabaseToLatestVersion();
}
```

The controller that I use to query the data is the following:

```
 [EnableQuery]
 public IQueryable<GenericArticle> Get()
 {
     var data = UnitOfWork.GenericArticlesRepository.Entities;

     return data;
 }
```

So, the method is marked with the `EnableQuery` attribute and the controller does also inherit from `ODataController`.

Now, there are some tables which I can query which contains millions of records, and off course, I don't even want a GetAll to find it's way to the database.

Therefore, I tought that in the `WebApiConfig` file, the following code was sufficient:

```
var queryAttribute = new QueryableAttribute
{
    MaxTop = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OData:MaxTop"]),
    PageSize = 2
};
```

However, this does not limit the results, but it throws an error when I request the url with a take filter which is more than the MaxTop value defined here.

Is there a way to ensure that, even if I request the url without any filter parameters, that the result will only contain the first 'x' records with paging enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try server paging option to filter the records in case if you want to restrict the number of records fetching.

Check this link - http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options#server-paging

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that I can do it by specifying it on the query, but I tought that there was a general place where I could define it (without writing custom attributes).